# Can a C++/CX library be used in .NET Core?

Tags: c++, .net, windows-runtime

As per title: Can a C++/CX library be used in .NET Core?

I wanted to know:
 * Can a C++/CX library be used by a .NET Core project? (Or "Portable" library) as a reference.
 * Can .NET Core or .NET Portable projects reference C++/CX libraries such as WinRT?

I have assumed that the first point is probably a "yes", but would appreciate a reference.  I have assumed that the second point is a "no", however, but again, would love a reference.

Comment: .NETCore is a collector term, it does not help you sort this out.  Only the platform matters.  C++/CX is intended to help create or use WinRT components when you use the C++ language.  Called UWP these days.  So the library is only usable in a project that targets Phone or Store or Universal.

Comment: There might be a managed C++ compiler for .NET Core, and the BCL of .NET Core might further grow. However, if your library sticks to WinRT closely and relies on the API .NET Core does not offer, then like @Hans said, the answer is NO.

Comment: I was afraid of this - this is what frustrates me with windows development; so many collector terms.  However, I'd still appreciate some references for this.